# NetBSD: how to mount a disk image?

Tags: netbsd

I have create a disk image on netbsd

```
newfs -F -s 10G 1.img
```

How to mount it?

I have tried "nodev" but give error and try to mount
/mnt/p2

```
mount -v -o nodev /home/user/1.img /mnt/p2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

First configure the image as "vnode", is similar to Linux losetup

```
vndconfig vnd0 /home/user/1.img
```

where is the fs?

```
  vndconfig -l /dev/vnd*d
  vnd0: / (/dev/dk1) inode 954267
```

mount it!

```
 mount /dev/vnd0 /mnt
```